# Node.js- Error when giving rout of request using variable routes

Tags: javascript, node.js

my App.js code is-

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.get('/', routes.index);

//var abt = require('./routes/about');
app.get('/about', routes.about);
```

my index.js code is-

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

my about.js code is-

```
exports.about = function(req, res){
  res.render('about', { title: 'Express' });
```

If I am giving rout of request `/about` is in same manner as `/` like `app.get('/about', routes.about);` this is giving me error-

```
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at C:\Users\arpit.dubey\Desktop\NodeEclips\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:290:11
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Router.route (C:\Users\arpit.dubey\Desktop\NodeEclips\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:13)
    at Router.(anonymous function) [as get] (C:\Users\arpit.dubey\Desktop\NodeEclips\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:308:16)
    at Function.app.(anonymous function) (C:\Users\arpit.dubey\Desktop\NodeEclips\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:414:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\arpit.dubey\Desktop\NodeEclips\app.js:35:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

**while app.get('/', routes.index); is working fine then why app.get('/about', routes.about); causing above error?**

Comment: Try to print `console.log(abt);`.

Comment: just like @BenFortune said, you need to use `module.exports`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: create a new common Js module in which you put each request handler you need for your routing:

For example: routes.js (that you should call "handler.js" or something like this"):

```
module.exports = {

 index : function(req,res){

 },
 about : function(req,res){


 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I do not see `routes.js` file, and, as far as I understand, you do require not file, but whole `routes` directory.

Here's the problem: when you ask node to require a directory, it looks for a file, name `index.js`, and processes it as usual file. In your case file `about.js` is never required, since it's not ever mentioned in index.js.

```
var routes = require('/routes'); // require '/routes/index.js'

routes.index // exports.index = function(req,res) {...}
routes.about === undefined // No exports.about in index.js
```

**Edit**

To make it super-clear. To make things work, you need following code in single file `./routes/index.js`:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
};
exports.about = function(req, res) {
    res.render('about', { title: 'Express' });
};
```

If you still want to split it to several files, you need either require all of them in `./routes/index.js` file, or create `./routes.js` file which will include all dependencies/

Comment: You can omit the file extension when requiring.

Comment: I do not say about 'you need extension', but a fact, that 'about.js' is never ever required - no wonder express says it is undefined.